# Compile .NET project in Docker using .csproj file

Tags: .net, docker

I need to compile and deploy a .NET application inside a Docker. In order to do this, I am using microsoft/dotnet Docker image. My problem is that this image needs a project.json file to compile the project, while my .NET project uses a .csproj file instead.

Do you know if there is either a way to transform the content of my .csproj file to a valid project.json or another Docker image able to work with my current .csproj file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaking the traditional .NET with [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core).
The docker images you're using are images of the .NET core environment. 
In the link above you can find all the explanations needed to run a .NET Core application.

There's no parallelism between .csproj file and project.json file. The former is a "description" of how a single .NET project is defined. The latter is the definition of a .NET Core application with the catalog of all its dependencies. You can think of it like a merge of .csproj .sln and packages.config files.